# Experiencing a Snapchat pixel issue due to missing hashed email and phone number during initialization

Tags: javascript, shopify, pixel, shopify-app, snap

I'm encountering an issue related to the Snapchat pixel in my implementation. The problem seems to be arising from the absence of hashed email and phone number during initialization. I believe this might be impacting the pixel's functionality. I'm seeking assistance on  to understand how to troubleshoot and rectify this issue effectively. Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Below is the Snap pixel code**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(e,t,n){if(e.snaptr)return;var a=e.snaptr=function()
      {a.handleRequest?a.handleRequest.apply(a,arguments):a.queue.push(arguments)};
      a.queue=[];var s='script';r=t.createElement(s);r.async=!0;
      r.src=n;var u=t.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      u.parentNode.insertBefore(r,u);})(window,document,
      'https://sc-static.net/scevent.min.js');

      snaptr('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        'user_phone_number': user.phone_number,
        'user_hashed_phone_number': user.sha256_phone_number,
        'ip_address':user.ip_address,
        'user_email':user.email,
        'user_hashed_email':user.sha256_email
      });
     snaptr('track', 'PURCHASE', { 'currency': 'AED', 'price': $price, 'item_category': $category, 'item_ids': [$item_id] });
      
    </script>
    <!-- End Snap Pixel Code -->
```